# Why are these CSS rules repeated so often?

Tags: html, css

I was looking at a single span element(for the top menu) [here][1] in the web inspector.

```
element.style {
}
html, body, br, hr, div, span, a, object, iframe, ul, ol, dl, li, dt, dd, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, q, address, small, big, cite, dfn, ins, del, i, em, b, strong, sup, sub, strike, pre, code, samp, kbd, var, tt, form, fieldset, legend, label, input, textarea, option, .nobox {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
Inherited from 
a {
    color: #b00909;
    text-decoration: none;
}
html, body, p, a, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
html, body, br, hr, div, span, a, object, iframe, ul, ol, dl, li, dt, dd, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, q, address, small, big, cite, dfn, ins, del, i, em, b, strong, sup, sub, strike, pre, code, samp, kbd, var, tt, form, fieldset, legend, label, input, textarea, option, .nobox {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
user agent stylesheeta:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: auto;
}
Inherited from 
html, body, br, hr, div, span, a, object, iframe, ul, ol, dl, li, dt, dd, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, q, address, small, big, cite, dfn, ins, del, i, em, b, strong, sup, sub, strike, pre, code, samp, kbd, var, tt, form, fieldset, legend, label, input, textarea, option, .nobox {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
Inherited from 
html, body, br, hr, div, span, a, object, iframe, ul, ol, dl, li, dt, dd, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, q, address, small, big, cite, dfn, ins, del, i, em, b, strong, sup, sub, strike, pre, code, samp, kbd, var, tt, form, fieldset, legend, label, input, textarea, option, .nobox {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
Inherited from 
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
}
html, body, p, a, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
html, body, br, hr, div, span, a, object, iframe, ul, ol, dl, li, dt, dd, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, q, address, small, big, cite, dfn, ins, del, i, em, b, strong, sup, sub, strike, pre, code, samp, kbd, var, tt, form, fieldset, legend, label, input, textarea, option, .nobox {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
Inherited from 
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
}
html, body, p, a, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
html, body, br, hr, div, span, a, object, iframe, ul, ol, dl, li, dt, dd, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, q, address, small, big, cite, dfn, ins, del, i, em, b, strong, sup, sub, strike, pre, code, samp, kbd, var, tt, form, fieldset, legend, label, input, textarea, option, .nobox {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

I'm trying to understand why the same rules are repeated over and over again.  It almost makes understanding just a single element difficult.

Comment: You can use something like http://www.cleancss.com/css-beautify/ to see whats going on, just paste the whole css and it beautifies it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a very close look at the `html, body, br....` rules in the inspector. You'll see that all the selectors are in grey except for one - the one whose highlighted (not dimmed out rule) **matches/cascades** to the element you're inspecting.

I selected div.container on this stackoverflow page and got this:

[image: I selected div.container on this stackoverflow page]

Also, if you want to see only the rules that are being applied to a specific element (and not where they come from), just select the **Computed** tab in the inspector:

[image: webkit style inspector]

Comment: @cadegalt - `font-size: 100%` matches the selected element and is being applied, but the strikethrough indicates that a more specific rule in the cascade is overwriting it.

Comment: @cadegalt - they are rules that are contained in the specific code block for the matched selector in the CSS code, but ones that do not apply to the current element that you are inspecting. Because `margin` is not inherited, but `font-size` is, then the browser's CSS parser applies the `font-size` rule that is on the `html` tag, to descendent elements, but it does not apply the `margin` to descendent elements (even though `margin:0; font-size:100%;` are contained within the same CSS code block in this case.

Comment: It's useful to be able to trace the cascade. So if you remove `font-size: 13px` on your current element, then you can see which rule, if any, further up the cascade then becomes applied to your element. More importantly, rules like `margin:0` on the `html` element are not inherited by child div's, they are just being shown in the inspector because it resides in the same code block of an inherited rule in the CSS.

Answer (score 4):

The sames rules are repeated, because they are inherited down from top to bottom. Think of a HTML document as a tree, the further you get down to the leafes, the more levels you pass, the more properties can potentially be inherited from upper-level elements (unless they are overwritten).

In most inspection tools you can hide properties that are inherited (or they show up in a different tab or tree structure).

[[CSS inspector] http://s10.postimg.org/fnrutg7zb/computed_Styles.png](http://s10.postimg.org/fnrutg7zb/computed_Styles.png)

Comment: Exactly. When a property is overwritten by another rule, it will be shown with strike-through text in the inspector. To get rid of all the clutter, simply hide the inherited properties. It will help you understand the actual structure better.

Comment: There is a checkbox at the very top of the properties tree saying **Show inherited**. Untick it.

Answer (score 2):

It shows the inheritance chain for the given element. That element is likely within `body`, so it inherits certain properties from it. It's probably also within a `div`, and maybe within a `ul` and a `li` and so on. It inherits properties from all these parent objects. Some properties will be overridden by more nested elements, in which case the parent's properties should be crossed out (the rules at the bottom of this list will likely be mostly crossed out).

In this case, the same rule (`html, body, br, ...`) applies to many elements. So this rule shows up again and again, for each parent that it applied to. Usually the particular part (`html` or `body` etc.) that applied to the particular parent should be highlighted.

This allows you to debug the entire inheritance chain both through the DOM parents and the applicative CSS rules at once. You can see which rule of which parent added a particular property to your element, or which property was overridden by which child. If you just want to see the result of all this inheritance, look at the computed properties section (in Chrome that's to the right of this list).

Answer (score 1):

Some CSS rules are inheritable. E.g. if you specify the `font-size` for the `body` it will also affect all its children.

So every parent of the inspected element inherits some values from his parent correspondingly. Just look at your body and you will see no inherited values. Look at the first element inside of the body and then you'll see that it gets an inherited value. Now look at its child: it has inherited properties from the body and from its parent (but its parent inherited some stuff from the body) - you get the same inherited things twice. This goes on until your element is reached.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing all CSS rules that apply to your element. It is possible that a CSS rule matches multiple elements (then you'll see it as you described here).

In the Web Inspector, you can select the magnifier before a CSS property to see which selectors are applied to this specific property.

Answer (score 0):

If you are beginner and used opensource css script,
It might include reset script in your opensource some where.
For example, @import "blabla/reset.css"
If it is, get rid of this line